# WOS2 API Manager not creating Service Provider automatically

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I've configured WSO2 IS as a Key Manager to API Manager following this documentation according to my version [Configure WSO2 IS as a Key Manager](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/4.1.0/administer/key-managers/configure-wso2is-connector/). My problem is that after I create and publish the API on DEVPORTAL the application is not created automatically on WSO2IS as a Service Provider.

I'm trying to invoke WSO2 Identity Server to generate the Access Token using password grant type:

```
https://<wso2-is>:<wso2-is-port>/oauth2/token
```

Request:

```
curl --location 'https://localhost:9444/oauth2/token' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic WWFKZ1kxaHVLdXRMd3ZoWDdhd2FLY29lOVRBYTp3SDM5QWJMNjNwMkhGa1FTT0xqWk5BSko2cnNh' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \
--data-urlencode 'username=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'password=admin' \
--data-urlencode 'scope=openid'
```

But I'm receiving:

```
{
  "error_description": "A valid OAuth client could not be found for client_id: ZL1gIStKIi1pQFlJpH9HdyZle5wa",
  "error": "invalid_client"
}
```

After a valid Acces Token I want to call the API on API Manager using this token.

WSO2-IS: 5.11.0 
WSO2-APIM: 4.1.0

Comment: Can you provide the payload you have sent with the above token url?

Comment: once you create the application, did you try to generate client key and secrete by clicking "Generate key" button on the devportal UI?

Comment: Creating and Publishing an API will not create any Service Providers in the IS KM. You have to create an Application from the Devportal and click on Generate Keys to create the Service Provider in the IS KM. Once that is successfully created, you can use the respective client ID and secret to acquire an Access Token from the IS KM directly. Using that, you can invoke the API as expected.